# Cannot enable encryption via keyring-file

Tags: mysql, docker, encryption, mysql-8.0

Ok, i'm following official Mysql docs to enable encryption on a mysql database on docker:

- [Using the keyring_file File-Based Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keyring-file-plugin.html)
- [Keyring Plugin Installation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keyring-installation.html)
- [keyring_file_data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keyring-system-variables.html#sysvar_keyring_file_data)

So here's what i've done:

1. added `early-plugin-load` and `keyring_file_data` to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (i used `echo stuff >> file` since mysql docker image has no text editor), so now it is:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
secure-file-priv= NULL
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# Custom config should go here
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
keyring_file_data=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring/keyring
```

1. created keyring file with

```sh
cd /usr/local/mysql
mkdir mysql-keyring
chmod 750 mysql-keyring
chown mysql mysql-keyring
chgrp mysql mysql-keyring
```

2. restarted container to restart mysql
3. connected to mysql and checked plugin availability (whith no luck) with

```sql
mysql> SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS
       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS
       WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';
```

4. Checked the logs for errors:

```
2020-03-15T12:30:08.669015Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011370] [Server] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'File '/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring/keyring' not found (OS errno 20 - Not a directory)'
2020-03-15T12:30:08.669036Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011355] [Server] Plugin keyring_file reported: 'keyring_file initialization failure. Please check if the keyring_file_data points to readable keyring file or keyring file can be created in the specified location. The keyring_file will stay unusable until correct path to the keyring file gets provided'
2020-03-15T12:30:08.669053Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010202] [Server] Plugin 'keyring_file' init function returned error.
```

So it look like that i correctly enabled the plugin, but something is wrong with the file.

Am i missing some steps?

## keyring file

```
root@8c3670db35d4:/# ls -la /usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring/
total 8
drwxr-s--- 2 mysql mysql 4096 Mar 15 12:34 .
drwxr-sr-x 3 root  staff 4096 Mar 15 12:33 ..
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql    0 Mar 15 12:34 keyring
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you created the keyring file correctly inside the container ? This is how I was able to achieve the above with a correctly crafted Dockerfile.

1. Create a folder for your image project (use whatever folder you like)

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/testMysqlKeyring
   cd /tmp/testMysqlKeyring
   ```
2. Create a mysql keyring dropin configuration file `keyring.cnf` with the following content:

   ```
   [mysqld]
   early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so
   keyring_file_data=/usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring/keyring
   ```
3. Create a `Dockerfile` with the following content

   ```
   FROM mysql:8

   # Place the dropin config file in the relevant folder
   COPY keyring.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/

   # Create the keyring folder and adapt perms
   RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring && \
       chmod 750 /usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring && \
       chown mysql.mysql /usr/local/mysql/mysql-keyring
   ```
4. Build image from the above configuration:

   ```
   docker build -t file_keyringed_mysql:latest .
   ```
5. Run a container from that image (you will adapt with your exact volumes and environment later...)

   ```
   docker run -d --rm --name my_keyring_test -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=true file_keyringed_mysql:latest
   ```
6. Check that plugin is correctly installed inside the container

   ```
   $ docker exec my_keyring_test mysql -e "SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';"
   PLUGIN_NAME     PLUGIN_STATUS
   keyring_file    ACTIVE
   ```

Comment: OK, updated my project and it worked, not sure if it is due the folder permission or the inclusion of the new `keyring.cnf` instead of the editing of the old `my.cnf`, thanks.